# Search for a string in webpage and print the entire line containing it using python

Tags: python, search

I would like to search a webpage for a string and print the entire line containing that string.

I have a input file containing the links that i would like to search for that string.

**String to be searched** : "vcore"

My Input File:

```
http://abc/cluster/app/application_1447334090028_225490
http://abc/cluster/app/application_1447334090028_228858
```

**Expected Output File:**

```
http://abc/cluster/app/application_1447334090028_225490    12434 vcore, 123 mb
http://abc/cluster/app/application_1447334090028_228858    12132 vcore, 131 mb
```

**Code so far**:

```
import sys
import re
import urllib

Links = [Link.strip() for Link in open ('/home/try/Input.txt','r').readlines()]

for link in Links:
        webPage = urllib.urlopen(link).read()
        print webPage
```

Then i use grep to search for the string and store it in another file. But i want it to be done by the code itself and the line to appear next to the corresponding link. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: "Lines" don't exist in HTML, only nodes and text.

Comment: Can you give a small sample input and output?

Comment: so, is there a way to get what i am looking for from the html page without bs4?

Comment: provided the input and output above

Comment: @blackfury You haven't provided any input. What does the `html` look like? Simplify it to the relevant details.

Comment: its just a normal html page with tags and stuff. I dont wanna use bs4 for this task. Its simple to just find the string and print the line. That is all that i am looking for. Lets say this is the link : http://www.digitalspy.com/tv/prison-break/feature/a664651/17-things-you-probably-never-knew-about-prison-break/ and this is the line that i am looking for: ENTERTAINMENT NETWORK

Comment: If it's simple, why are you asking the question?

Comment: I am sorry Peter... I am new to Python; Just trying to learn. I was told it was simpler. Just wanted to give it a try without bs4. Anyways, I will post a solution using bs4. Would like to know it without using that module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lines = urllib.urlopen(link).readlines()
for line in lines:
    if "vcore" in line:
        print line
```

Comment: works like a charm.... Just having blank lines in the output. Thank you Steve :) I have updated ur code to print along with the links

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import urllib

Links = [Link.strip() for Link in open ('/home/try/Urls.txt','r').readlines()]

for link in Links:
        lines = urllib.urlopen(link).readlines()
        for line in lines:
                if "vcore" in line:
                        print link,line
```

Just having blank lines after every print statement

Comment: each line ends up with a '\n', so, to delete the blank line, try: print line.strip()